Is there a Graph API resource type for all managed app?
I need to target an Intune App Protection Policy to All Apps using Graph API. The URI being used is    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/androidManagedAppProtections/{ID}/apps.
I found resource types for all devices and all licensed users. Is there one for all managed apps?

allDevicesAssignmentTarget https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-shared-alldevicesassignmenttarget?view=graph-rest-1.0
allLicensedUsersAssignmentTarget https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-shared-alllicensedusersassignmenttarget?view=graph-rest-1.0

GETs for a policy targeted to all apps list every app. I suspect that looping to add every Intune managed app would only work until a new managed app is added.

I did not need a resource type for all managed apps. The following JSON set the targeted apps to All apps.
{
    'appGroupType': $targetApps,
    'apps': []
}

